# How do I use Gatling 2.1.2 to test a page with lots (150+) of formParams?

Tags: gatling

I have a form that I'm trying to test with Gatling 2.1.2[*] (on Windows) that has many (150+) inputs. I can use the recorder to create tests for other pages with fewer inputs. When I generate a simulation from submitting this page and run gatling.bat with that simulation in the simulations folder, the compiler fails silently. The code the recorder generates looks like this:

```
.exec(http("request_1")
        .post("/saveform")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .formParam("data[item][0][value]", "hammer")
        ... [~150 more formParam lines] ...
        .formParam("data[item][40][comment]", "Needs more work")
        .headers(headers_2)))
```

I suspect that the problem has to do with the limit on Scala method lengths. I've confirmed this by deleting about half of the .formParam calls; after doing this the compiler succeeds and I can run the simulation. The general advice seems to be to move the exec items to an object, but the formParam chains are so long that even in their own object, the compiler fails silently.

```
object SaveFormLibrary {
    val saveFormChain = http("request_1")
        .post("/saveform")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .formParam("data[item][0][value]", "hammer")
        ... [~150 more formParam lines] ...
        .formParam("data[item][40][comment]", "Needs more work")
}

class ItemSimulation extends Simulation {

  import saveFormLibrary._

  val scn = scenario("saveForm").exec(saveFormChain)
  [...]
}
```

Is there some way to break up the exec chain even more? I tried defining methods to run parts of the chain, but I can't figure out how to make it work with Http Request being a DSL. The last thing I tried was:

```
def getForm(form:HttpRequest) = {
    getFormHelper(form)
        .formParam("data[item][25][value]", "stamp")
        [...]
        .formParam("data[item][40][comment]", "Needs work")

}
def getFormHelper(form:HttpRequest) = {
    form
        .formParam("data[item][0][value]", "hammer")
        [...]
        .formParam("data[item][24][comment]", "Buy more")

}

[...]
val scn = scenario("saveForm").exec(getForm(http("request_1")
        .post("/saveform")
        .headers(headers_0)))
```

This throws an error that HttpRequest is undefined, and I'm not sure if there's an object type that would work, since I'm unfamiliar with how Scala and DSLs work. Am I on the right track, or am I thinking about this completely incorrectly?

[*]EDIT: I was previously using version 2.0.0. Upgraded to 2.1.2 and am seeing the same behavior.

Comment: First of all, please upgrade to a recent version. I think the silent compiler failure issue was fixed since 2.0.0. Latest version is 2.1.2.

Comment: Updated to 2.1.2, still getting the exact same behavior. No errors or warnings, but the simulation script doesn't show up in the options ("There is no simulation script[...]"). I cut 133 lines of .formParam and it compiles ("ItemSimulation is the only simulation, executing it[...]").

Comment: Would you mind sharing your full simulation in a gist or pastebin, please?

Comment: Original simulation: http://pastebin.com/HyYaGfvz, and a smaller version that works: http://pastebin.com/Lb6y9zQf

Comment: I've open an issue: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/2495

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Gatling 2.1.2 and below. It's fixed in 2.1.3.